# REGEX condition with non-capture groups

Tags: php, regex

I've got the Regular Expression:

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+?)[ ]?(\()?(?(2)([A-Za-z0-9=\-\/°%= ]*)\))_([A-Za-z0-9]*)$
                          ^
                          |
                       condition
```

It should match following:

```
name (unit)_type
name(unit)_type
long_name_type
name_type
```

The problem is that I've got 4 capture groups instead of 3:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => name
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => (
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => unit
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => type
    )
```

However when I change the capture group for parenthesis to non-capture group like that:

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+?)[ ]?(?:\()?(?(2)([A-Za-z0-9=\-\/°%= ]*)\))_([A-Za-z0-9]*)$
                     ^
                     |
                    here
```

It does not work.

Is there any chance to get matches like that?

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => name
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => unit
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => type
    )
```

EDIT:
After all your tips I've simplified it like that:

```
(\w+?) *(?:\(([A-Za-z0-9\/°%= -]*)\))?_([A-Za-z0-9]*)$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you really need that regex condition.

Why not simply use an optional non-capture group:

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+?)[ ]?(?:\(([A-Za-z0-9=\-\/°% ]*)\))?_([A-Za-z0-9]*)$
                     ^^^^                         ^
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/mQ2kI0)

[Note: you have 2 `=` signs in the character class, I removed one of them since it's redundant to use two in a character class]

Comment: That's great.
+1 for a nice regex101 tool
If I have more pluses I would give you another for simplifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could simplify it down quite a bit using `\w` and eliminating some unnecessary character classes. You can then use your non-capture groups:

```
(\w+?) *(?:\(([A-Za-z0-9\/°%= -]*)\))?_([A-Za-z0-9]*)$
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/wZ8nP8

Also, you don't need to escape `-` in a character class if it's at the beginning or end.

Per suggestion by @nhahtdh fixed up the last section to exclude `_` (back to character class). Also noticed that the previous example broke `long_name`.

Comment: Last one is not `\w`. The original code does not include `_`. Same for the middle one.

Comment: @nhahtdh point, but since the _ is declared explicitly before, either it will occur (and should probably be captured) or it won't (and it doesn't matter). OP could replace `\w` with `[A-Za-z0-9]` again though.

Comment: You should mention these things explicitly in your answer - since it is a difference between acceptance or rejection.

Comment: @nhahtdh you're right -- fixed it up. It was breaking `long_name`.

Comment: Another thing is that `\s` will allow the regex to match something across lines... And the `\w` also allows `_`, while it does not present in OP's code.

Comment: @nhahtdh `\s` will only match if it's a multiline regex, but you're right, it should be more explicit.

Comment: Nope. Multiline option affects ^ and $, and doesn't have anything to do with `\s`. http://regex101.com/r/oC4qX2

Comment: r3mus Thanks for giving me opportunity to learn new REGEX characters.
I've noticed at the beginning that regex failed for long name, due to \w. Now I see it's much much better.

Thanks @nhahtdh for good points about explicity. 

I've updated the answer, but I still see that r3mus is improving the answer, so I will update it finally later :)

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue I think @nhahtdh makes some good points and I've updated this answer to reflect your specific conditions (because you're including underscores in some, but not all, of the captures. If you want to include an underscore between the `(unit)` bit, you could replace that `A-Za-z0-9` with `\w`. If not, then don't :)