# Regex conditional non-capturing group

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I am trying to extract the email`s username if the email is from a specific domain. otherwise, get the full email. I need the result to be set in Group 1.

**test@example1.com => test**

**test@example2.com => test@example2.com**

here is my regex

```
^(.*)?(?:@example1\.com)|(?=@example2\.com)$
```

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079392/regex-condition-with-non-capture-groups) but no luck.

Comment: Are `example1.com` and `example2.com` the only allowed domains?

Comment: no, any domain is allowed.

Comment: It would be much easier if, rather than capturing the result to group 1, you could simply convert matches of the regular expression `@example1.com$` to empty strings. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wVKmGp/1)

Comment: If all your inputs contain e-mails, how about just [`^(.+?)(?:@example1\.com)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/WJpbpC/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for your input. Regex has to match the whole email and then capture either username or full email into a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(.+?)(?:(?:@example1\.com)?|(?=@))$
```

This uses a non-greedy quantifier inside the capture group, so it will only match up to `@example1.com` if that domain is in the input. Otherwise it uses a lookahead to require that there be `@domain` in the input.

We put a group around the alternatives so they don't split the whole regexp into separate alternatives. Your regexp only has the capture group in the first alternative.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iLvCEO/2)

Comment: Sorry, how this `(?=@)$` expected to be matched ever? Shouldn't you regex simply be `^(.+?)(?:@example1\.com)?$`?

Comment: @markalex It's to ensure that when there's no `@example1.com` there's still an `@` somewhere, so it only matches an email.

Comment: 1. Your pattern [accepts](https://regex101.com/r/usgIma/1) input without @. 2. `(?=@)$` can never work: nothing can be immediately followed by @ and end of line at the same time. 3. Second branch of alteration is never reached. `(?:@example1\.com)?` covers all cases and is always matched (with empty string but still matched). Your regex is effectively equivalent to `^(.+?)(?:@example1\.com)?$` but with unreachable blocks.

Comment: Oops, you're right. If I remove the `?` after `(?@example.com)`, it doesn't match the other cases.

Comment: @Zeedia you should not accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the regular expression

```
(.+(?=@example1\.com$)|.*)
```

for the specified domain `"example1.com"`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/csfVFq/1)

If, instead of saving the result to capture group 1, it can simply be what is matched by the regular expression, which often is regarded as  capture group 0, you could use the regular expression

```
^.*(?=@example1\.com$)|.*
```

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(                   # begin capture group 1
  .+                # match one or more characters other than
                    # line terminators, as many as possible
  (?=               # begin a positive lookahead
    @example1\.com  # match "@example1.com"
    $               # match end of string
  )                 # end the positive lookahead
  |                 # or
  .*                # match zero or more characters other than 
                    # line terminators, as many as possible
)                   # end capture group 1
```